# Whats a good naming convention for part series and shunt components?

Tags: antenna, matching

I have an RF receiver circuit which includes a ceramic chip antenna. Our chip antenna manufacturer "fine tunes" this antenna to the board and housing by determining the values of the Shunt and Series components. Throughout all of the designs we've had so far, Shunt01 is left NP. The Series and Shunt02 components will sometimes change from an inductor to a capacitor or vice versa.

However, our Reference designators are listed as C1 for the Series component and L1 and L2 for Shunt01 and Shunt02 respectively.

**But since these components sometimes change depending on design, is it good practice to change the ref des to something like Z1, Z2, Z3??**

[image]

Comment: In the broader scheme of things (like who's making the sandwiches or where's the nearest toilet) it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real convention for the thing you are asking about. But yes it would be a great idea to change the site designators to Z1, Z2 etc like you suggested.

The main point to be made is to find something that works for you and the folks that get involved with the antenna tuning.

Comment: This is how I do it, too.  However, beware of possible confusion with your units.  Specifying Z1 to be "3.3n" could be interpreted as either 3.3nF or 3.3nH.  Keep your BOMs straight!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to put dual markings on the same footprint.. CXX / LXX. That might (or might not) reduce confusion at various stages.

Answer (score 0):

In my design, I use LK1, LK2 as reference designators